# cmake response files Unix Makefile generator vs ninja generator

Tags: cmake, ninja

CMake 3.4.1 is using response files to shorten command line length for linking with ninja but not unix makefiles. I'm cross compiling with the IAR embedded toolchain and it doesn't support the given response file syntax (i.e. @CMakeFiles/proj.rsp). I'd prefer to use the ninja build system, as its faster, but I need a workaround for this response file. Either I need to disable response file generation or get it to use a syntax that my toolchain supports (i.e. -f filename). Is there a way to do either of those?

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work for me, although there may be smarter ways to go about doing this. I wouldn't be surprised if the build generator doesn't use response files if the command line is short enough.

```
if ( ${CMAKE_GENERATOR} MATCHES "Ninja" )
   set(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE "<CMAKE_LINKER> -f CMakeFiles/${PROJECT_NAME}.rsp <LINK_FLAGS> <LINK_LIBRARIES> -o <TARGET>")
endif()
```